# ${\rm Aut}(S_4)$ are all inner automorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, automorphism-group

I have been able to follow the hints given in Hungerford and I have proved the fact that if $\sigma \in{\rm Aut}(S_4)$ and $\sigma$ fixes all the sylow-3 subgroups of $S_4$ then it is an identity map,  however how am I going to show that if $\phi:S_4\to{\rm Aut}(S_4)$ then the map is surjective?

Can someone explain with some examples as to why this will hold true (not any proof but examples as to why any other form of automorphsim except inner automorphism will not be an automorphism)

Comment: Every automorphism permutes the Sylow 3-subgroups.

Comment: And all automorphisms that permutes the sylow-3 subgroups are inner?

Comment: The way in which I am proceeding is  it correct?

Comment: Let $\tau \in {\rm Aut}(S_4)$. Then $\tau$ permutes the set $X$ of the four Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_4$. But these Sylow subgroups correspond to the four points permuted by $S_4$, because each of them fixes a unique point. So there is an inner automorphism $\sigma$ that induces the same permutation of $X$ as $\tau$. So $\tau\sigma^{-1}$ fixes all Sylow three subgroups, and you have already proved that this implies $\tau = \sigma$.

Comment: What are fixed points? Also showing a simple isomorphism from $S_4->Aut(S_4)$ and then using the fact that $S_4$ is isomorphic to Inn($S_4$) will not do my work? if not then why?